# Which was that Marshall's game with that spectacular Queen sac?

Tags: history

Which was the game where Marshall, I think that with Black, made a spectacular Queen sac in g3 (White pawns on f2, g2, and h2, King in g1).  The Black Queen could be taken with the f and h pawns and also with a third piece, and all variants led to different checkmate themes.

I believe that the audience started throwing gold coins after Qg3 was made.

**UPDATE**: I changed Murphy's mentions in the original question to mention Marshall instead, as Marshall was the player who actually did the Queen sac.

Comment: I don't think the gold coin thing really happened.

Comment: The gold coin story is indeed a myth, but the move itself is quite spectacular :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it was Levitsky vs Marshall

```
[FEN ""]
1. d4 e6 2. e4 d5 3. Nc3 c5 4. Nf3 Nc6 5. exd5 exd5 6. Be2 Nf6 7. O-O Be7 8. Bg5 O-O 9. dxc5 Be6 10. Nd4 Bxc5 11. Nxe6 fxe6 12. Bg4 Qd6 13. Bh3 Rae8 14. Qd2 Bb4 15. Bxf6 Rxf6 16. Rad1 Qc5 17. Qe2 Bxc3 18. bxc3 Qxc3 19. Rxd5 Nd4 20. Qh5 Ref8 21. Re5 Rh6 22. Qg5 Rxh3 23. Rc5 Qg3   (23... Qg3 24.Qxg3 Ne2+ 25.Kh1 Nxg3+ 26.Kg1 Nxf1 27.gxh3 Nd2)
```

Comment: Isn't this the one they call 'The Marshall Swindle' ? :-)